# How to add a many2many field to inherited model

Tags: orm, many-to-many, odoo-12

I try to add a many2many field as below:

```
_inherit = 'mail.compose.message'

    partnercc_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.partner', relation='mail_compose_message_res_partner_cc_rel',
                                     column1='partner_id', column2='wizard_id',
                                     string='Additional Contacts')
```

The table "mail_compose_message_res_partner_cc_rel" has not been added. I wish you can help me

Comment: did you import this file in `__init__`?

Comment: it works when i imported the file. thank you